# How can I use hardware keys (Yubikey and Titan Key) with multiple applications?

Tags: flutter, mean-stack, webauthn, fido-u2f, yubikey

I am developing a Saas application, that implements the 2 Factor Authentication feature, using hardware keys **(Yubikey, Titan Key)**, using **WebAuthn/U2F** protocol.
The feature is working well for registering and authenticating in web version.
However, my application have also a mobile version, a desktop application, and browser extensions. If i register the key using the web version, i am not able to authenticate in other versions.

I think the problem is because when registering the key is registered using the domain name of the web version, and the verification fails when i uses other versions, because it is not the same domain name.

For example: my key is register with the domain name is **example.com**, and when logging in from the chrome extension the domain is **chrome-extension**.

How i can solve this issue, or how i can do the authentication from different forms of the same application.

Answer (score 1):

WebAuthn credentials are scoped to an [RP ID](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#rp-id). A website, `www.example.com` can use the RP IDs `www.example.com` and `example.com`. (Roughly you can remove labels from the left of the domain, but not as far as an effective TLD, so no RP ID of `com`.)

Mobile apps can use any RP ID, but the domain has to authorise them by listing them in a file in `/.well-known/`. (The details differ between [Android](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/v1/getting-started) and [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/connecting_to_a_service_with_passkeys).)

Chrome extensions can only use the `chrome-extension:`… RP ID, however. You aren't the first to ask about whether that can be extended, and the [Web Extensions CG](https://www.w3.org/community/webextensions/) might end up defining something, but there's nothing currently I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes apparently there is no solution. The key should be authenticated from the same platform it was registered. Should have another verification mode for other devices.